# How can I improve asyncio lock mechanism

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, locks

Below is my code where I have implemented asyncio lock mechanism which is supposed to block a request in the method, if the request with same name is already in execution and has not completed yet which is working fine, but the problem is if the request comes with different name that is also getting blocked which is not ideal,  ideally it should be that if the request comes with different request name that should start its execution without having to wait

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
 
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_lock(req_name_):
    locks = {}
    logger.info(f"Creating lock for stack {req_name_} if not created")
    if not locks.get(req_name_):
        logger.info("creating key for a lock")
        locks[req_name_] = asyncio.Lock()
    async with locks[req_name_]:
        yield
    if len(locks[req_name_]._waiters) == 0:
        del locks[req_name_]
        logger.info(f"lock released")
    logger.info(len(locks))

async def handle_lock_request(req_json_):
    logger.info(f"ocupying lock")
    req_name = req_json_.get('req_name')
    async with get_lock(req_name):
        logger.info(f"lock acquired by stack {req_name}")
        await _handle_request(req_json_)

async def _req_handler():
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    logger.debug("Await receiver.recv_string")
    req = await receiver.recv_string()
    logger.debug(f"Request received {req}")
    req_json = json.loads(req)
    logger.debug("Await create_task")
    tasks.append(loop.create_task(handle_lock_request(req_json)))
    await asyncio.gather(*[task for task in tasks if not task.done()])
  
def _handle_request(req_json_):
    # ...
    # ...
    logger.info(f"Request finished with req name {req_name} for action patch stack")
```

Comment: Your `locks` dict needs to live outside the scope of `get_lock()`. Right now you are creating a new lock for every request, regardless. So I wouldn't expect for any requests to wait on a lock.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion it worked well by keeping the locks dict  outside the get_lock()  but i had to make slighter change to my code by removing this line  
await asyncio.gather(*[task for task in tasks if not task.done()]) because of this line  it was making it execute one after the other even after keeping locks dict outside the get_lock() `

Comment: Can you please tell how this works in case if the lock is acquired and somehow it is not released because of some error or if request took too much time to complete how can i timeout already  running request? can you please explain the timeout scenario

Comment: The call to `gater()`, which you removed, is not the culprit for your requests running sequentially. As you pasted it into your question, your code will not run, because `_request_handler()` is not an async function. I don't now what your actual code is, but I assume your `request_handler()` is a sync function blocking your event loop. It needs to be async or run in a thread.

Comment: About timing out requests: Please don't expand the scope of your question in the comments. Open a new question instead.

Comment: can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603619/how-can-i-add-timeout-to-the-task-that-are-waiting-to-acquire-the-lock

Answer (score 0):

Updated
Remove the asyncio.gather() part from the code and just call the create_task

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

locks = {}
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_lock(req_name_):
        logger.info(f"Creating lock for stack {req_name_} if not created")
        if not locks.get(req_name_):
            logger.info("creating key for a lock")
            locks[req_name_] = asyncio.Lock()
        async with locks[req_name_]:
            yield
        if len(locks[req_name_]._waiters) == 0:
            del locks[req_name_]
            logger.info(f"lock released")
        logger.info(len(locks))


    async def handle_lock_request(req_json_):
        logger.info(f"ocupying lock")
        req_name = req_json_.get('req_name')
        async with get_lock(req_name):
            logger.info(f"lock acquired by stack {req_name}")
            await _handle_request(req_json_)
     
     async def _req_handler():
         tasks = []
         loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
         logger.debug("Await receiver.recv_string")
          req = await receiver.recv_string()
          logger.debug(f"Request received {req}")
          req_json = json.loads(req)
          logger.debug("Await create_task")
          loop.create_task(handle_lock_request(req_json))
          
  
     def _handle_request(req_json_):
       ...
       ...
       logger.info(f"Request finished with req name {req_name} for action patch stack")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Both the question and the answer are unclear to me. The question wants an improvement, but what is the problem in the first place? The answer is just a lot of code, which problem is solved and why? Also code is not documented and should be split in smaller routines, where each function has a single function and responsibility. Give proper function names: handle_something() is not clear to me and too generic. Then, add documentation so you see how it works. Tell the user in a few lines when to use this code m.